# Meaning of 十五【とご】

Tags: translation, words, readings

The word has been seen in the manga ハヤテのごとく！

After finishing last, Hayate is given a card with no money on it but “unlimited debt”:

[image: panel from ハヤテのごとく！ vol. 46 p. 28]

The full sentence reads

> そちらは入金が一切ない代わりに十五{とご}で無制限に借金が出来る『うしじまカード』となっております。

What could 十五 mean here? If it does mean “fifteen”(percent?), why is it not read じゅうご?

Comment: [This article seems to be relevant](https://saimusos.net/yamikin/53#toc7)

Comment: And うしじま refers to [this manga series](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%97%87%E9%87%91%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B8%E3%83%9E%E3%81%8F%E3%82%93).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Jimmy Yang's linked page suggests, トゴ is slang used in the context of usury, meaning 十日{とおか}で五割{ごわり}. Taking the first kana of each word we get トゴ. It is an illegal practice to loan money at an abusive interest rate: 50% every 10 days. In Japan it is known as 闇金{やみきん} (black market loans). Such high interest is called 高金利{こうきんり}.

> トゴは10日経過するごとに5割の利息がつく方式で、3つの中では最も高い金利です。トゴで10万円を借りると10日で5万円、20日で10万円、30日で15万円の利息です。([source](https://saimusos.net/yamikin/53#toc5))

Comment: `10日で5万円、20日で10万円、30日で15万円` しかし闇金は**複利**なので、10日で5万(借金が15万になる)、20日で5+7.5(←15万×0.5)=12.5万(借金が22.5万になる)、30日で12.5+11.25(←22.5×0.5)=23.75万の利息(借金が33.75万になる)です

Comment: @Chocolate I thought that too... I thought interest would become part of the principal and the new principal should be used to calculate interest in the new cycle. But I wasn't sure because I haven't had any real life experience with this...